# What is the difference between fixed point and floating point processor?How float is handled in both kinds?

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am bit confused about how floating point operations are handled in a processor which is do not support floating point operation.
Again how floating point processor is different from fixed point processor?
In which case IEEE floating point formats are used?

Comment: If you want help with your homework, can you please give your own answer first? We are not here to answer your homework questions.

Comment: nope..I am working on writing some DSP algorithms for my own interest(in C).I am not sure which processor should I use to implement them.Please note I am having very less knowledge about processor architectures.It would be good if you add some suggestions also..i.e. when to select a DSP,floating point DSP or other processor.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off there are a number of different floating point formats, for various reasons.  (some) DSPs do not use IEEE for performance reasons, it carries a lot of extra baggage (which most folks never use).

From elementary school we learned how to count then we learned how to add which is just a short cut for counting, then we learned to multiply which is just a short cut for adding, likewise subtraction and division are shortcuts for counting down rather than counting up.  We also learned to do all of our math one column at a time, so if you have a processor that can do at least 1 bit math operations you can do addition, subtraction, multiplication and division as wide (As many bits per operand) as you desire, it may take a lot of operations but it is quite doable and anyone that made it through grade school has the tool box/skill set to do such a thing.

floating point is a middle school thing, manipulate a decimal point and use powers of some base (1.3 * 10^5) + (1.5 * 10*5).  we know we have to get the 10 to the powers the same then we can just do basic elementary addition with the decimal points lined up.  multiplication is even easier as you dont have to line up the decimal points you just do the math on the significant digits and simply add the exponents.

When your processor has a multiply instruction, it is just a shortcut for you having to do multiple additions (the shortcuts usually involve multiple additions).  What they do is depending on how many clock cycles they want to get the multiply operation down to uses an increasingly large amount of chip real estate.  Likewise for division, that is why you dont see divide on a lot of instruction sets and dont see multiply on some of the ones that dont have divide, it is a cost trade off, performance vs power and chip real estate, yield, etc.

Then floating point is just an extension of that at the core of a floating point operation you still have the fixed point operations, a floating point multiply requires a fixed point multiplication and an addition and some adjustment.  A floating point addition requires some adjustment, an addition and some more adjustment.

Now what processors have fpus and what dont?  What processors with an fpu support ieee and what dont?  That is as easy to find as the information above, but I will leave you to solve that yourself.

if you are for example able to do math operations using scientific notation (1.345*10^4 + 2.456*10^6, or 2.3*10^6 * 4.5*10^7) then you should be able to break down the math steps involved and write your own soft float routines, not optimized but you can see how a cpu that either doesnt have an fpu or a programmer that doesnt want to use the fpu can do floating point operations.  You have to be able to think in terms of base 2 not ten though which makes the problem significantly easier  1.101001*2^4 + 1.010101*2^5, in particular multiplies get real easy.

Comment: IEEE defines the bit formats for the mantissa and exponent and sign, which can add more code/logic depending on implementation.  Then on top of the basic math operations it adds rouding, three modes, and exceptions and other interesting things.  All of which you can pull directly out of the spec and implement in software code or logic code, "if X result and Y is enabled then the result is Z"  an operation on a signaling nan for example or getting a "properly signed infinity" from a divide by zero.  a soft fpu library simply implements those rules in addition to the math.

Answer (score 0):

When floating point is not supported in hardware, the calculations are done by heavily optimised pieces of assembly code, usually from a library.

One Google search away you could have found [this about fixed-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).  I assume you can find info about IEEE floating point yourself ;-)

Good luck!

Comment: Well, usually by calling functions in a FP library that is linked in.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation and arbitrary fixed point library can be found **[here](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?module=Freaks%20Academy&func=viewItem&item_type=project&item_id=2351)**.